# Exposing docker-compose services to the HOST machine as well

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, host

Here is my `v3.5` `docker-compose.yml` definition file. It has an `analytics` network (using an alias of the same name), and where both included services connect to said network to communicate with one another. This works.

However, I want these services (ports) exposed to the HOST machine, as well. There's a way to do that by defining an additional network and/or specifying additional `ports:` entries within the services themselves, but I can't figure out exactly how because the documentation is very confusing and version-specific (moving targets).

Without destroying the below (because it works internally), what additions do I make (and where) to expose both services to the HOST machine as well?

Thank you!

```
version: '3.5'

networks:
  analytics:
    name: analytics
    driver: bridge

  # ===========================================
  # Service: Zookeeper
  # ===========================================
  zookeeper:
    image: 'wurstmeister/zookeeper:latest'
    container_name: analytics-ZooKeeper
    networks:
      - analytics
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    volumes:
      - ./data.d/zookeeper.d:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.9/data
  # ===========================================

  # ===========================================
  # Service: Kafka
  # ===========================================
  kafka:
    build:
      context: ./kafka.d
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: nmvega/kafka:latest

    networks:
      - analytics
    ports:
      - 9092-9094:9092 # For one to three Kafka brokers.

    environment:
     #KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: vps00         # Docker host Name. <--- BEFORE
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.0.180 # Docker host IP.   <--- AFTER
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181

    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./data.d/kafka.d:/kafka

    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
  # ===========================================
```

**EDIT**:
Upon further investigation, the above configuration, as originally posted, is correct with the small modification from the `name` of the Docker Host to the `IP` of the Docker host (as prescribed by the [readme for the image](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker) that I'm using). Accidentally using the `name` didn't matter until I attempted to access the service from the Host.

Hopefully this example will be valuable to others wanting to see one.
Thank you to the commenters below.

Comment: when you do  ports: - "2181:2181" , you are mapping the host:container ports. So I don't understant your question

Comment: I thought that maps the internal-container port onto the defined virtual-network (`analytics`) either as the same or different port; ... not all the way to the host network. But then again, this is docker and I'm willing to be wrong. I'm double-checking now b/c the port range for the Kafka service above could be blindsiding me.

Comment: one problem can be the range, because you are putting the range like three ports in the host to one port in the container. try to put the same number of ports, like 9092-9094:9092-9094

Comment: @andre_vieira Your first comment was correct. My issue turned out to be something else, which I explained in the `EDIT` section of the post. As for your port-range suggestion, you'd normally be correct but in this case there will actually be three instances of the container via `docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.yml scale kafka=3` (which is run after launching the initial one). Thanks again.